# regex query text between < and > symbols

Tags: regex

I have a big list of email addresses in a format that I can't use for script them, I need help to build a regex that can match the email addresses.

```
name1 surname1 <name1.surname1@domain.com>
name2 surname2 <name2.surname2@domain.com>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex query to achieve it is

```
\<(.*?)\>
```